# Notation for codomain

Tags: functions, notation

Let $X, Y$ be sets, and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ a map. Is there a standard notation for the codomain of f? cod $f$, maybe? 
I know that in category theory, specifically in **Set** there exists a function (of classes) from Mor(**Set**) to Ob(**Set**) that assigns the 'target' to each morphism, but that seems cubersome..

Comment: Is there any point to category theory other than highflautten verbiage to obscure the issue at hand?

Comment: In my book it designated as $Ra(f)$ (from `range`)

Comment: @ShimonS: The range is not the codomain, it's a subset thereof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you mean that `range` and `image` are the same?

Comment: @ShimonS: Hm. Right. Some people do use range to mean codomain and then image to mean range.  It's all very confusing without more context.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Seems that `some people` wrote [our course book](http://prntscr.com/oogicv) :)