# Domain, codomain, range and image of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused by the concept of domain, range, co-domain and image set of a function.

For example, I have $f:[0,5] \ \to [\frac{1}{5}, \infty]$, defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

I would like to ask the questions:

1. What is the domain of $f$ ? Is it $[0,5]$ or $(0,5]$ ?
2. Is the range, codomain and image of $f$$: [\frac{1}{5}, \infty]$ or $\mathbb{R}$ ?
3. What is the condition for 2 functions $f$ and $g$ to be equal ?

Thank you very much!

P/s: This question on mathexchange relates but not fully satisfies my concern
[Domain, Codomain, Range, Image and Preimage](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3278686)

Comment: Your example abuses the standard notation: writing $f:X\to Y$ means the domain is $X$, and that $f$ is a function - your "rule" doesn't apply to every point of the domain so you've not yet said what function you have in mind.

Comment: @ancientmathematician: thanks for your comment! Could you please be more specific, I don't clearly understand your point ?

Comment: We'd have to begin by you answering a question: what precisely is your definition of a function? And as you've flagged the question "real-analysis" what does the symbol "$\infty$" signify?

Answer (score 1):

Domain D is set of all real values of $x$ for which the function takes real,finite and unique value. Range R is all values taken by the function over all the $x$ values of the domain. A set larger than the the range is co-domain C. Infinity is never included in D and R. So in your example $$D=(0,5], ~~R=[1/5,\infty),~~ C= \Re (Real)$$

Image is $f(a)$, the value of function at $x=a$ when $a \in D$. Set  of all images is nothing but the range R. $x=a$ can also be called pre-image of $f(a)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you add some explanations about the term "image" of $f$ ?

Comment: You may see the added statement in my answer now.